# jQuery dataTable 1.9.4 fnReloadAjax gives "TypeError: k is undefined" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

JQuery dataTables are used extensively in our web app, and usually they don't give a problem. But there's this one that has this bug where during the execution of fnReloadAjax, it gives the error "TypeError: k is undefined", which is coming from the dataTables.js line where "fnServerData:function(e,j,m,k)" occurs. Here's the dataTable definition:

```
    url = '?p=user.creation_rules_browser&page_action=getData';
data_table = jQuery('#data').dataTable({
    bJQueryUI: true,
    sDom: '<"template-box"fl><"template-box"ip><"template-box"r><"ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all template-box" t><"template-box"p<"toolbar">>',
    sAjaxSource: url,
    bPaginate: false,
    bProcessing: true,
    bAutoWidth: false,
    bSort:false,
    bFilter:false,
    bInfo:false,
    aoColumns: [
                { "bSortable": false },
                { "bSortable": false },
                { "bSortable": false },
                { "bSortable": false },
                { "bSortable": false },
                { "bSortable": false },
                { "bSortable": false }
            ]
    } );
```

It loads up perfectly, but there's a column with an action menu that lets you edit the row. This pops up a jQuery Dialog which executes the following when you hit "Save":

```
jQuery.getJSON('index.php',{
    p: "user.creation_rules_browser",
    page_action: "edit_rule",
    rule_name: rule_name_val,
    target_field: $('#input_target_field').val(),
    action_value: action_value_val,
    action_set_to_blank: action_set_to_blank_val,
    id: data.id
}, function (json) { 
    if (json.error) {
        Dialog.alert({title: "Error Saving Rule"}, json.error);
    } else {
        jQuery(self).dialog('close');
        url = 'index.php?p=user.creation_rules_browser&page_action=getData';
        data_table.fnReloadAjax(url);
    }
}
```

The Save actually works, but the dataTable doesn't get reloaded because of that error. It should go back to that url and "getData" and reload, but it gets stuck in fnServerData because k is undefined. This k corresponds to oSettings in the non-min fnServerData declaration, but I've done a console.log and verified that fnGetSettings returns the expected copy of oSettings. Originally, url wasn't being passed in the call to fnReloadAjax, so I thought that might be a problem and added it in, but got the same result.

So I don't get why it's undefined. I guess my next step would be to use the non-min version of dataTables.js, and add some debugging in there, but I'm hoping somebody here will find some simple thing that's being done wrong in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I found where obsolete versions of dataTables and fnReloadAjax were being loaded in addition to the current versions. Taking that out fixed it.